# WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium in Python 2.7 and I get the following error,

> WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but
>   unable to find binary in default location, no
>   'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
>   set on the command line

Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid this issue in two different ways:

1. Explicit where to find firefox binary to your selenium code:

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
   from selenium import webdriver
   firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/')
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
   ```
2. Add firefox to your PATH environment variabile. [Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without passing the argument in "firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/')"

The working code for me is -

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the accepted answer, but applies when the default binary location is already correct. This is a different use case from what the question asked.

Comment: Yeah my default binary location is already correct. But it is not a different use case. It can be a use for many different user. So posted my answer as well coz the accepted answer was not working for me. When I passed 'firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/')' without the arguments, then it worked.